# How to make css width same as height when height is not known and may differ (height is dependent on other dynamic factors)?

Tags: css, flexbox

The height of the concerned element(element with the class "child") equals to the height of the content of its sibling (set by `align-items: stretch` by its parent element). The codes are shown below

The height of the `div.child` is automatically set and may differ. I want the width of this element to always match its height. 
In short, I want the `div.child` to be always square.

The Codepen link of the demo--> https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.parent .child {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"> I want to set the width of this element equals to its height (which is equals to the height of the content of it's  sibling, set by `align-items : stretch`) </div>
   <div class="child childs-sibling">
          some text <br>
          some text <br>
          some text <br>
          some text <br>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify what you're trying to achieve, also you had a typo at align-items: stretch

Comment: Are you saying you want that first "child" DIV to always be square?

Comment: @ChrisLi there was a typo which confused. it's "i want to set the width" , not "i want to set the height"

Comment: @MSC yeah exactly

Comment: @Neel please explain in the detail

Comment: @SanjayPrajapati The height of the div(class=child) is automatically set and may differ. I want the width of this element to always match its height